# SparkSql with JDBC Connection

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

I want to read data from a database using Spark's JDBC API. I will be using 200 executors to read the data.

My question is that if i have provided 200 executor then will it create 200 connection to centralized database(JDBC) or will it fetch data from driver with single connection?

Answer (score -2):

When you establish connectivity `spark.read.jdbc...` you can specify `numPartitions` parameter. That manages max limit of how many parallel connection can be created.

> The maximum number of partitions that can be used for parallelism in table reading and writing. This also determines the maximum number
>   of concurrent JDBC connections. If the number of partitions to write
>   exceeds this limit, we decrease it to this limit by calling
>   coalesce(numPartitions) before writing.

However, by default you read data to a single partition which usually doesn’t fully utilize your SQL database.

Comment: In isolation `numPartitions` has no effect. It is used only if combined with other properties.

Comment: @user8371915 of course, but nevertheless this parameter control parallelism.

Comment: If and only if it is combined with bounds and partition column and predicates argument is not provided. Otherwise it is ignored

Comment: It works for *limiting* the number of connections used for writing though. Then `numPartitions` must be specified as an option to the `DataFrameWriter` (like `dataset.write().option("numPartitions", 50)`), not to the `DataFrameReader`. Then it will limit the number of connections used for writing with a "coalesce" operation.